# Prove $(A_1 \smallsetminus B) \cup (A_2 \smallsetminus B) = (A_1 \cup A_2) \smallsetminus B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove $(A_1 \smallsetminus B) \cup (A_2 \smallsetminus B) = (A_1 \cup A_2) \smallsetminus B$

If I used the set identity to prove it and it seems it goes on and on, did I make a mistake or ...

$(A_1 \cap \lnot B) \cup (A_2 \cap\lnot B)$ and then I use the distributive law and ...

$((A_1 \cap \lnot B) \cup A_2) \cap (A_1 \cap \lnot B) \cup \lnot B)$

Comment: Yes, you would have made a mistake.  The proof does not 'go on and on'.  It is reasonably straightforward.  However, there is no telling where mistake might be without knowing *what* exactly you tried to do.

Comment: I am sorry that question might seem dumb or my brain is not functioning well. How do I type the union and intersection sign?

Comment: @Bob use cup and cap tags on LaTex.

Comment: It is a good question, @Bob .  Here's a [Mathjax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I wish I could just write it down

Comment: You will get used to it.  Anyway, distribution is the next step, but you have to distribute *out* the common factor: $$(A_1\cup A_2)\cap\lnot B_1 = (A_1\cap\lnot B)\cup(A_2\cap\lnot B)$$  Distribution is an equivalence -- it works in both directions.

Comment: What the "distributive law"? you say "...." as though the next steps leads to ... what?  The way I see it the next step leads to one thing and then.... stops.

Comment: I guess it is a really dumb question since I distribute ((1∩¬)∪2)∩(1∩¬)∪¬) and then it goes on and on

Comment: @fleablood A *common mistake* is to distribute in : $(A_1\cap\lnot B)\cup(A_2\cap \lnot B)=(A_1\cup A_2)\cap(A_1\cup \lnot B)\cap(A_2\cup \lnot B)\cap(\lnot B\cup \lnot B)$ .

Comment: Instead of trying to prove $(A_1\setminus B)\cup (A_2\setminus B) = (A_1 \cup A_2)\setminus B$.  Try to prove  $(A_1 \cup A_2)\setminus B = (A_1\setminus B)\cup (A_2\setminus B) $.  Use the distributive law as you know it on $(A_1 \cup A_2)\setminus B$; not on $ (A_1\setminus B)\cup (A_2\setminus B) $.  (.... or use the distributive law in the *other* direction. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the distributive law just $(M\cap N) \cup (S\cap N)= (M\cup S)\cap N$?

So $(A_1\setminus B)\cup (A_2\setminus B) = $

$(A_1\cap B^c)\cup (A_2\cap B^c) =$

$(A_1\cup A_2)\cap B^c =$

$(A_1\cup A_2)\setminus B$.

Doesn't seem to go "on and on".

Comment: My bad, oof I used the distributive law the other way around

Comment: Sorry I was trying to figure out how to type those symbols instead

Answer (score 0):

Distribution is the next step, but you have to distribute *out* the common factor.  You may be familiar with distributing like this. $$(A_1\cup A_2)\cap\lnot B_1 ~=~ (A_1\cap\lnot B)\cup(A_2\cap\lnot B)$$  However, note that distribution is an equivalence -- it works in both directions.
$$(A_1\cap\lnot B)\cup(A_2\cap\lnot B) ~= ~(A_1\cup A_2)\cap\lnot B_1$$